# EXTjS 3.4.0 cell selection and highlight

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am trying to make a grid which we can select some cells in same row and can highlight those selected cells by any color in EXTjS 3.4.0 .
I tried:

new Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel;
'cellclick':function(grid,rowIndex,cellIndex,e)

Comment: Check this thread. It may help you, https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?117585-extjs-how-to-change-CSS-in-a-grid-cell
In extJS 5 and above   `cellclick : function(a, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts){
            td.style.background = "red"
        }` But below that you have to do some hack.

Comment: Yeah Buddy,,I found it using cellclick event and some css code....thanks